# Shortcuts sync between iOS simulator and watchOS simulator

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios-simulator, apple-watch, sirishortcuts

I'm developing an app for iOS and Watch OS that handle a shortcuts. The iOS app correctly handle the intent both calling the shortcuts from the Shortcuts app and by Siri. The WatchOS app should handle natively the intent and it does calling the shortcuts from the Shortcuts app (on the watch) BUT NOT calling the shortcuts with Siri.
The problem is that I'm not able to debug the watch app because:

- In the simulator the shortcuts on the iOS device doesn't sync with the watchOS device: I've tried everything, also the "force sync shortcuts to watch" option. I have no shortcut on the watch and then I can't check on the simulator watch log. **How can I sync shortcuts from iOS sim e watchOS sim?**
- Using a real iPhone device and Apple Watch the problem is reading the watch log: most of the times the Consol app on Macbook doesn't trace the log streaming (I don't know why sometimes works and other not). **Where am I wrong?**

Thank you in advance for your help

Current config: MacBook Pro M1, Xcode 13 beta 3, iPhone 12 Pro max with iOS 15 beta 3, Apple Watch 6 with watchOS 8 beta 3

Comment: Same problem. My watch app’s Siri intents work on watchOS 7 but not on 8. I get a “something went wrong message “. Please post a response if you find a solution

Comment: Were you able to find a solution? Experiencing the same exact issue :/